# jQuery Validation engine : How to use the 'showOneMessage' property?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using [jQuery.validationEngine](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) in one of my forms. Problem is when there are multiple required fields missing the form gets flooded with those floating red validation error per input field.

There is property mentioned in the documentation called [showOneMessage](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#options/showonemessage) which is suppose to only show the first validation but i'm not able to get it to work. 
here's a working [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6ESCD/) with added `showOneMessage` attribute which doesn't seem to be doing anything.

anyone knows how to get the `showOneMessage` working? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used, tested (Nov 2012) and it works:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#formIDhere").validationEngine('attach', {showOneMessage: true});    
    });
</script>
```

Looks like this was known and addressed by the author 2 months ago. Maybe make sure you have the latest code?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version tried the code above and it didn't work. I even just changed the default value for showOneMessage in the plugin and it still didn't work and showed all the messages.

Comment: The latest code on git says 2.6.4, but when you download and open up the main js file, it says 2.6.2 still.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {maxErrorsPerField:1});
```

or

In validationEngine.js, change default `maxErrorsPerField:False` condition to `maxErrorsPerField:1`